# Script Error when open .chm disappear when opening through the debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, chm

I get a number of script errors and none of the images will be shown when I open a .chm file on my computer. If I esc all error messages and refresh (twice) then the .chm is shown correctly. Although I need to do this for each new page.

I have made all recommended fixes for .chm files! Reregistrered, unblocked, fixed paths,... The errors is for all .chm on the machine

But, here is my real question, if I run this program, with a .chm file as argument, through the Visual Studio 2013 debugger then the .chm is shown correctly!

The problem is probably in my Windows configuration, but somehow the debugger "fixes" this error and get it to work. Does the debugger have it's own configuration that isn't dependent on the actual Windows configuration?

```
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace xcute
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                string f = args[0];

                Process.Start(f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here are the error dialogs
[image: LoadLoad Script Error]

[image: No Images]

Comment: If you get any error messages you need to post those messages here. "Something is wrong" is not a good problem description.

Comment: Displaying help in a web browser is fine, many programs do so today.  But when you package the HTML pages into a .chm file then you'll have to remove the javascript from them.  The CHM help viewer does not try to be a functional web browser.

Comment: The .chm file that the screen dumps are from is made using SandCastle Help File Builder so any jabascript is made by it. The file works on "all" other computers... My question isn't about the actual script error, but if the debugger does something to the Windows environment, since the .chm file works perfectly if I open it from the debugger with the attached code. The code doesn't work if I run it outside of the debugger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem (well sort of)!

If I open the .chm as administrator then everything works! So obviously I have some permission error on my computer. The reason it worked when I ran my program in the debugger is that Visual Studio is started as Administrator...

But since I'm a programmer I solved the issue by creating a small program that start hh.exe as admin. I get the UAC consent form but I can live with that.

// Anders

The program:

```
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                Execute(args[0]);
            }
        }

        private static void Execute(string chmFile)
        {
            const int ERROR_CANCELLED = 1223; //The operation was canceled by the user.

            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Windows\hh.exe");
            info.Arguments = chmFile;
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            info.Verb = "runas";
            try
            {
                Process.Start(info);
            }
            catch (Win32Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_CANCELLED)
                    Console.WriteLine("Why you no select Yes?");
                else
                    throw;
            }
        }
    }
```